# Drop down size of spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

[image: Cities list has around 400 items and maximum size of spinner is 400dp but it is showing only one item as you see in the image.PS:It is not the case everytime.sometimes it is showing maximum size.]I am dynamically populating the spinner based on response from previous selected item.Though the size of list is more than 1 ,size of drop down is sometimes showing only one item(Slider is working). It is not happening everytime.Sometimes it is showing maximum size and sometimes not.

Maximum size of drop down is 400dp.

```
<com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCollege"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:ms_dropdown_max_height="400dp"
                app:ms_background_color="@color/offWhite"/>

new CityPresenter().getCities(new OnEntitiesReceivedListener<City>(this) {
            @Override
            public void onReceived(final List<City> cities) {
                UpdateProfileActivity.this.cities = cities;
                final List<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<>();
                for(City city : cities){
                    cityNames.add(city.getName());
                }
              //  Collections.sort(cityNames);
                Log.d(TAG,cityNames.toString());
                cityNames.add(0,"Select City");
                citySpinner.setItems(cityNames);
}
}
```

Expected to show more than one item in drop down but showing only one item.

Comment: The xml code is not sufficient to locate the error. Add some related java code.

Comment: Edited.pls have a look at java code.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use final in List<>?

Comment: Why is this after the for loop.
cityNames.add(0,"Select City");
I think its replacing previously added value in the foor loop at 0 index.
Try adding this line before the for loop starts.

Comment: But sometimes it is showing drop down with higher size.sometimes not. I don't think that problem is over there.

Comment: The ArrayAdapter Code is missing, could you kindly add that too above. The issue is diificult to find here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have set your adapter but this is generally how I get dynamic spinners working.

**Dynamic List Spinner**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get reference of spinner from XML layout
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.mySpinnerId);
    //Using this button to trigger spinner list change
    Button myButton=findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);

     final List<String> myArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
     myArrayList.add("Some String");
     myArrayList.add("Some Other String");
     //And....so on

     final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,myArrayList);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

     //Triggering the spinner list change using a button
     myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        myArrayList.add("New Item");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

}
}

Hope this helps you to identify and resolve the issue.